# Wordpress/CSS - Submenu hover dropdown styles added to navigation bar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, navigation

I have a responsive navigation bar that I have added to a WordPress theme. But I would like a submenu drop-down to be added to my responsive navigation bar but im unsure how to do this. I am new to PHP and WordPress.

---

HTML

```
                <?php

                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary'
                );

                ?>

                <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>
        </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
   nav {
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        background: #86c024;
        font-size: 11pt;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width:1000px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    .clearfix {
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    nav a {
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 40px;

    }
    nav li a {
        padding: 0 10px;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    nav li a:link, a:visited {
        color: white
    }
    nav li:last-child a {
        border-right: 0;
    }
    nav a:hover {
        background: #2098d1;
    }
     nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:link,
    .site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:visited {
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #2098d1;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: none;
    } 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    nav { 
    height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {

    nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background: #86c024;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: url('img/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('#pull');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

---

additional CSS attempt

```
ul.sub-menu { /* this targets all sub menus */
    display: none; /* hide all sub menus from view */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 40px; /* this should be the same height as the top level menu -- height + padding + borders */
}

ul.sub-menu li { /* this targets all submenu items */

    width: 100px; /* set to the width you want your sub menus to be. This needs to match the value we set below */
}
ul.sub-menu li a { /* target all sub menu item links */
    padding: 5px 10px; /* give our sub menu links a nice button feel */
}
ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    display: block; /* show sub menus when hovering over a parent */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have adjust some of your css and html, please check its working now.

the main problem is in the height of `nav` also I have change the position of `a#pull` to the top of the `ul`.

```js
 $(function() {
   var pull = $('#pull');
   menu = $('nav ul');
   menuHeight = menu.height();

   $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     menu.slideToggle();
   });

   $(window).resize(function() {
     var w = $(window).width();
     if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
       menu.removeAttr('style');
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #86c024;
  font-size: 11pt;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}
nav li a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav li a:link,
a:visited {
  color: white
}
nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #2098d1;
}
nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
.site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:link,
.site-header nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:visited {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #2098d1;
}
nav a#pull {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background: #86c024;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('img/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
  }
}
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. the dropdown does not show up and the mobile version just overlaps the parent tab.

Comment: you can check the mobile view in "responsive design view" in Mozilla

Comment: The responsive design worked, Im looking to have a dropdown for the submenu. This is within wordpress.

Comment: you don't have any style(css) for submenu in desktop as well.

Comment: No I don't, I'm not sure how to style it.